# automatic scrollable scrollview with textview

Tags: android, android-layout

Why isn't my Scrollview automatic scrolling? I don't get it.. it just doesn't move...

```
package com.lernapp.src.Activities;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.lernapp.src.R;
import com.lernapp.src.Database.DbConfig;
import com.lernapp.src.Database.LernAppOpenHelper;

public class StartMenu extends Activity {

    private ScrollView scroller;
    private TextView text;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.startmenu);

        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        Button infoButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startmenubutton4);

        infoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
            public void onClick(View v) {

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)StartMenu.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(
                   inflater.inflate(R.layout.infopopup, null, false), 
                   300, 
                   400, 
                   false);

                pw.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());    
                pw.setOutsideTouchable(true);               
                pw.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.startmenumain), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.infopopup, null, false);

                scroller = (ScrollView)view.findViewById(R.id.scroller);
                text = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.scrolltext);

                scroller.post(new Runnable() { 
                    public void run() { 
                        scroller.smoothScrollTo(0, text.getBottom());
                    } 
                });

            }
        }); 

    }   
}
```

and popupxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/scroller">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="test\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\n "
        android:color="#FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/scrolltext"/>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not only use a TextView, it can scroll horizontally.

```
android:elippsize="marquee"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Comment: Because i want that it scrolls automatically

Comment: With that parameters the TExtView scrolls automatically, like a marquee :).

Comment: Mh.. but how can i scroll vertically?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your height to wrap_content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:padding="10dip" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="#000000" 
    android:id="@+id/scroller"> 

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip" 
        android:text="test\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\ntest\n " 
        android:color="#FFFFFF" 
        android:id="@+id/scrolltext"/> 

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Hmm, you might also try setting your TextView to wrap_content height as well.

Comment: Ah, misunderstood the question!  Is your scroller.post runnable getting called?

Comment: its like the post isnt called at all.. but i did add a logcat output in this thread.. and it was called ONCE...